# Контроль ввода в QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Есть QLineEdit, в которое нужно вводить только вещественные значения(например, maxAccelerationValue).[image: Окно параметров]

Я так понимаю, тут есть два варианта.

1. QValidator.

Хорошо, я определяю регулярное выражение:

```
#define DOUBLE_RX "^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$"
```

Затем в конструкторе самого окна выставляю для QLineEdit валидатор:

```
    ui->maxAcceleration_line->setValidator(valiDouble);
```

Однако всё равно можно вводить и иные символы кроме цифр и точки.

2. Проверка на ввод числа

У QLineEdit делаю слот:

```
void ParametersWindow::on_maxAcceleration_line_editingFinished()
{
    double temp = ui->maxAcceleration_line->text().toDouble();
    if (!isdigit(temp))
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Неправильный формат ввода", "Введите вещественное число");
}
```

В этом случае выходит сообщение даже при вводе вещественного числа. При нажатии Ок у диалога окно параметров закрывается. А если не закрывается, то курсор перескакивает на другую QLineEdit.

Подскажите, как корректно реализовать?

UPD:
Создал валидатор для вещественных значений и установил его для QLineEdit:

```
QDoubleValidator *valiDouble = new QDoubleValidator(this);
ui->maxAcceleration_line->setValidator(valiDouble);
```

Затем по окончанию ввода в текстовое поле проверяю валидность:

```
void ParametersWindow::on_tauSafe_line_editingFinished()
{
    if(ui->tauSafe_line->hasAcceptableInput()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Ошибка ввода", "Введите вещественное число");
    } else {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Ввод корректен", "Это вещественное число");
    }
}
```

Чтобы я не вводил, даже вещественные значения, всё равно критикал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ввода вещественных чисел есть готовый [QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QDoubleValidator.html). В сомом простом случае использование элементарное:

```
ui->maxAcceleration_line->setValidator (new QDoubleValidator (this));
```

Самодостаточный минимальный пример:

```
// Build with: g++ -I/usr/include/qt4/{QtCore,QtGui,} -lQt{Gui,Core} -o validator main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDoubleValidator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit;
    le->setValidator (new QDoubleValidator(le));
    le->show ();
    return a.exec ();
}
```

> Однако всё равно можно вводить и иные символы кроме цифр и точки.

С регэкспом тоже можно, но где-то допущена ошибка. За отсутствием полного кода, где именно — сказать не смогу.

> Проверка на ввод числа

Способ сам по себе плох, а в реализации написана какая-то околесица.

Comment: Но тем не менее, всё в поле ввода можно вводить что угодно. В какой момент срабатывает валидатор? В момент прекращения ввода или ввода символа? Как можно отследить возвращаемое значение?

Comment: в момент ввода. В этот момент `QLineEdit` вызывает `QValidator::validate()` и в зависимости от того, что он вернул допускает или нет ввод символа. почему у тебя не работает сказать не могу — вероятно какая-то глупая ошибка... например не тому виджету назначил валидатора... если думаешь, что не так, то [mcve] в студию...

Comment: Ок, добавил upd. Больше ничего не использую

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, во-первых, валидатор добавляется к `maxAcceleration_line`, а проверяется в `tauSafe_line`, во вторых логика работы `on_tauSafe_line_editingFinished ()` прямо противоположная: «если ввод допустимый. то выдать ошибку».

Comment: Ну, там много полей, я для примера копипастнул не ту, но подключено ко всем

Comment: Да, спасибо. Глаз замылился уже в код смотреть.

Comment: Однако не работает

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, ищи ошибку ;) больше добавить нечего...  приложил однофайловый пример — посмотри как должно работать...

Comment: Нашёл. Не в том конструкторе фигачил. Спасибо за помощь ещё раз